# If I scroll and refresh my webpage, my nav header loses its properties. JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I scroll my nav header goes from transparent to a solid color and it works perfectly fine. But whenever I refresh my page halfway down my nav header loses its properties and it seems as jquery resets and my nav header is back to transparent. I want it to stay a solid color if I refresh my page and I'm halfway down the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('.header');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.header').css('background-color', '#111417');
       } else {
          $('.header').css('background-color', 'transparent');
       }
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state in a cookie and whenever page refreshes, read the state from the cookie and set appropriate css or classes.

```
 $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.header').css('background-color', '#111417');
           //here save the cookie for example class or the css
       } else {
          $('.header').css('background-color', 'transparent');
           //here save the cookie
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

In document ready, simply trigger the event, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('.header');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.header').css('background-color', '#111417');
       } else {
          $('.header').css('background-color', 'transparent');
       }
   });
   $(document).trigger("scroll");
});
```

You may need to set a short setTimeout on the trigger command of a quarter second, or maybe even do it on window.load, but that should trigger your scrolling functionality into occurring on page load, regardless of where the browser puts the user on refresh.